# Why Won't the Followers of the Apocalypse message me?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

ED-E got his keywords triggered and a couple days later, as expected, I got a message from the Brotherhood of Steel. No message from the Followers ever hit though, it's been several more ingame days and still no message. Anybody know why it won't play? As it is, I can ONLY go to Lorenzo to get the Brotherhood +8DT armor for him, which I don't want. Is there a way to fix this without using Console commands, or will I have to reset the quest entirely?

Note: I had gone through REPCON HQ a while before this and picked up the stuff from the broherhood paladins there. Could that have messed that up the quest? It read it as me already having gone there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Fallout New Vegas Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/ED-E_My_Love) states:

> If you have already received the holotape note by previously exploring REPCONN Headquarters, April won't contact you until you open the metal gate that surrounds Hidden Valley or, if entering from the gap in the fence, until you have entered the Brotherhood compound.

April is the NPC from the Followers who contacts the player in this quest.